# jQuery word frequency counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've fried my brain looking at this for too long.  With the following little JavaScript:

```
 var words = 'one two three four one two three';
        wordArray = words.split(' ');
        var newArray = [];
        var words = {};
        words.word;
        words.count;
        $.each(wordArray, function (ix, val) {
            if ($.inArray(wordArray[ix], newArray) > -1) {
                newArray[wordArray[ix]].count++;
            }
            else {
                console.log('that wasnt in the array');
                newArray.push(wordArray[ix]);
                newArray[wordArray[ix]].count = 1;
            }

        });
```

I get the error `cannot set property 'count' of undefined`. Why can't I dynamically add the property and have anything work fine?

Comment: Where is newArray defined?

Comment: `newArray[wordArray[ix]]` uses `newArray` as an object whose properties are the word names. But it's just an array whose values are strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newArray` should be an object whose properties are the words and values are the count:

```
var newArray = {};
$.each(wordArray, function (ix, val) {
    if (newArray[val]) {
        newArray[val]++;
    }
    else {
        console.log('that wasnt in the array');
        newArray[val] = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, a simple one-liner `newArray[val] = (newArray[val] || 0) + 1`

Comment: @meagar Cryptic one-liners are not conducive to education.

Comment: I was simply sharing an alternate implementation, not suggesting that you change it. That said, I don't find it all all cryptic, quite the opposite: I would write it that way because it's one trivial line which makes for a clearer loop than the same loop containing five lines. Perhaps it's my Ruby background, but I find `(a || b) + 1` is extremely obvious and comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

seems like you are trying to invent a property count on the Array. I think you just want `length` unless `newArray` is something other then the native Array object. if it is just a `["word", "another"]` then you don't need to do anything to increment the length property it is done internally

**UPDATE**
ok then defninately the problem is the `count` property `newArray.length` will do what you are trying to do with `.count`

**UPDATE 2**

ok so it looks like you want to do this:

```
    var words = 'one two three four one two three';
    wordArray = words.split(' ');
    var newArray = [];
    var words = {};

    $.each(wordArray, function (ix, word ) {
        if ($.inArray(word , newArray) > -1) {
            words[word]++;
        }
        else {
            console.log('that wasnt in the array');
            words[word] = 1;
        }

    });
```

this would give you an object where the word is the key and the value is the count like:

```
{ "one": 2, "four": 1} //etc
```

Comment: Faster than me... Gratz.
Error is self explanatory. It is trying to set a property of 'count' which is what you are doing instead of what I think you want to do.

Comment: I messed up and forgot an important chunk of the code.  I'm trying to get a count of repeat words in the wordArray variable.  Apologize for the screw up.